# Extending a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Extend $f(x)=x^2+x$ defined  in $[0,3]$ onto the interval $[-3,3]$ so that $f(x)$ is
>
> 1. even
> 2. odd

I can't understand this question. Can you please make the question more simple so I can understand what I need to do to solve it.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of odd and even functions to start with?

Comment: Yes I know the meaning of odd and even function

Comment: Now try plotting $y=x^2+x$ for $0\leq x\leq 3$

Comment: I plotted,now what?

Comment: Now look at it and think about what the graph would look like if it was an even function on the interval $-3\leq x\leq 3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) find a function $g$ that has the same values as $f(x)$ for $x \in [0,3]$ and for all such $x:g(-x)=g(x)=f(x) $

(ii) find a function $g$ that has the same values as $f(x)$ for $x \in [0,3]$ and for all such $x:g(-x)=-g(x)=-f(x)$

Comment: But what is it about [-3,3] the question have?

Comment: it is included there (implicitly), because the $-x$ for $x$ in $[0,3]$ is in the range $[-3,0]$. Since you have to define the function for x and -x, the resulting definition must be known for values in the range $[-3,3]$

Comment: Then simply [-3,3] is my new domain of definition?

Comment: Well, yes.but you do not have to look for a function that is not defined outside this interval, it suffice that the function is defined at least on this interval and you simply say that this interval is your domain of definition (since the question itself asks only for this interval)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1. What is an even function?
2. What is an odd function?
3. What must $f(x)$ on $[-3,0)$ look like so it is even?
4. What must $f(x)$ on $[-3,0)$ look like so it is odd?

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with the definition of the function on $[-3,0)$

For the even extension you need to arrange
$$
g(x)=g(-x)
$$
and for the odd extension you need to arrange
$$
g(x)=-g(-x)
$$
To construct an even function from a function $f(x)$
$$
\frac{1}{2}( f(x) + f(-x) )
$$
To construct an odd function from a function $f(x)$
$$
\frac{1}{2}( f(x) - f(-x) )
$$